# Is anti-aliasing still relevant in a high resolution display?

Tags: visual-design, screen-resolution

The idea of anti-aliasing is to make edges look smooth so it is nicer for human eye to see. But lately with the availability of high-resolution monitor, with high density per inch, which some called as "retina display", is anti-aliasing still required to improve the quality of the image? With such high ppi, human eye is no longer able to distinguish adjacent pixels, so it may look unnecessary to implement AA that will only burden the GPU.
Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: Most monitors don't have high enough ppi to omit any-aliasing (and those that have are pretty damn expensive).

Comment: You are right, rich people owning retina displays are no longer able to distinguish adjacent pixels.

Comment: @CodesInChaos What about mobile phone's display? Nowadays even 5.5-inch phone has 4K resolution.

Comment: My laptop's resolution is over 1080p but it's still extremely obvious to me when I run a game with the anti-aliasing off. The human eye is just really good at spotting those sharp, unnatural, jagged changes.

Comment: Are you talking about AA for rendered text, or for 3D games?

Comment: @CodesInChaos I'm more of talking about 3D games, as those are the things that AA will make the performance suffer. Ixrec says he/she is still able to spot jagged change at over 1080p, but in the future, we will likely see increase in display resolution, but not physical dimension, i.e. you will see 8K, 16K resolution on 24 inch display, but you are not likely to use a 60-inch monitor. So in that point of time, will AA be obsolete, and that we can just leave it off to improve performance?

Comment: You are correct in that as pixels get smaller, the need for Anti-aliasing decreases. In theory, there's a point where it becomes irrelevant.

Comment: @DA01 but we haven't reached that point yet. Even on 4k phone screens.

Comment: @DA01 what that 'point' is is probably a matter of opinion and age (how good are one's eyes) :) But I'd say the iPhone 6 is pretty damn close...as are newer eink screens like the Paperwhite

Answer (score 6):

I'll keep this brief. Yes, anti-aliasing is still very relevant. The reason is that the human eye can see subpixel movements on most displays. You'll often see pixels per degree as the metric used and reference 60 PPD for "retina" displays. The human eye at the center of vision has [hyperacuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperacuity_%28scientific_term%29) of small pixel movements that go past 400 PPD. So things like rendered lines that are moving on a high contrast background can appear jarring without AA even though they are very tiny.

Try this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/w5se983j/4/ Walk away from your monitor and you'll see the pixels moving.

That said these AA techniques usually only apply to animation and thin lines. It's very possible that if all you're displaying are images with very little contrast between adjacent pixels that AA will offer very little.

Comment: Not sure I understand the connection between PPD and 'pixels moving'. Yes, one would see pixels moving on high PPI devices, but not sure that correlated to anti-aliasing, does it?

Comment: The point is that anti-aliasing improves the display, so even with a display where _usually_ you don't notice pixels, there are situations where you do, so anti-aliasing still helps.

Comment: The pixels he is talking about moving are the pixels of the image, not the pixels of the display. Images on computer displays are very often not static.